# Pasar variable de python a php o evitar imprimir por pantalla en php

Tags: php, python

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intentando pasar un valor de python a php, la forma en la paso valor de php a python es de la siguiente forma (código python):

```
import sys
sys.argv[1]
```

Y de esta forma es llamo al archivo python desde php:

```
system('python3 ' . __DIR__ ."/../Py/file.py view")
```

Hasta ahí no hay nada malo ya que python si recibe los datos correctamente, pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es que php reciba datos con python, ¿alguien me puede decir como puedo hacer eso? lo intente en python haciendo un print de la siguiente forma:

```
parameter = sys.argv[1]
print(parameter)
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto eso desde php imprime el valor en la página, y lo que realmente busco es que python devuelva el valor sin imprimirlo en la pantalla, tambien he intentado hacerlo desde una funcion y que haga un `return` pero no llegan los datos, o tambien me gustaría si me pueden decir si hay alguna forma desde php de evitar que imprima datos, agradezco su ayuda. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, creo que te sirve utilizar el parámetro $return_var de la función system(), o también lo que retorna system(), que es la última línea de la salida del comando invocado: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.system.php

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que dices cuando indicas "cuando ejecuto eso desde php imprime el valor en la página" si lo entiendo bien, es el funcionamiento correcto de print() ¿qué quieres hacer exactamente? Trabajar los datos sin imprimirlos en pantalla?¿

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP intente de la forma en la que dijiste, pero aun así la funcion system sigue mostrando el resultado en la pantalla

Comment: @NandoMerino si justo eso, quiero trabajar con los datos sin imprimirlos en la pantalla

Comment: Pues si print(parameter) te lo imprime por pantalla, indica que has guardado correctamente el valor en la variable parameter, a partir de ahí haz lo que quieras hacer con ello, no hay más.

Comment: @NandoMerino pero entonces como guardo mi archivo python?

Comment: Tal vez con ob_start() puedes impedir que salga por pantalla, y recuperarlo con ob-get-contents() si lo necesitas. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-contents.php#example-515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logré resolver mi problema tal como dijo Jóse Carlos PHP, usando la función [ob_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-contents.php#example-515) de php, de esa forma ya no imprime el resultado en la página, por lo que el código php queda así:

```
        ob_start();
        
        system('python3 ' . __DIR__ ."/../Py/file.py view);

        $result = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
```

Mientras que el código python se queda totalmente igual:

```
parameter = sys.argv[1]
print(parameter)
```